# can a purple onion plant thrive on water-only?

Tags: plant-care, growth, hydroponic, onions

Is this article, [29 Plants That Grow in Water Only (Without a Hydroponic System)](https://thepracticalplanter.com/plants-that-grow-in-water/)
accurate, that is, can a plant thrive with only water?

I ask this question since, from the half of a purple onion grew a shoot, and it seems that thrives on the local tap water, but I have doubts in case were necessary put minerals or other kind of stuff.

[image: rikkkimaru]

Comment: Water has no nutrients, OTOH onion is the nutrient storage for the plant. You may add some dirt. But what it your target/purpose? If it is just Flowers and or seeds, it should be ok. To eat onions? No way. Onions are more then just water (and carbon)

Comment: For flowers and seeds. No problems in adding some dirt, but if I add it, how do I know that the plant is not going to die since is accustomed to water environment....

Comment: There's never a guarantee a plant won't die, especially if its roots are disturbed. But your pretty onion is doing as well as it is, as Giacomo Catenazzi says, because it's using up its reserves, not because the water is giving it all the kinds of molecules it needs.  It isn't "accustomed" in a sense of having long-term viability.